# How to Take screenshot while in fullscreen opengl game Delphi?

Tags: delphi, opengl, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Take screenshot opengl game ? for Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709059/how-take-screenshot-opengl-game-for-delphi)

I need help.I need take screenshot fullscreen opengl game delphi sources.

Comment: Have you checked the link I've posted to your previous question ?

Answer (score 2):

here's something I've cooked up, you haven't specified the Delphi version, so this is wrote in D2010, unfortunately the only game I have is counter-strike 1.6, and the result is a **black** image, but I'm pretty sure you can work your way from here(it's a rush job, but I haven't much time), so here's the code:

```
function TakeGameShot(const AFileName: string; const AWidth, AHeight: Integer): Boolean;
var
  LPixels: array of Byte;
  LLine: PByteArray;
  LBitmap: TBitmap;
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  LBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    LBitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
    LBitmap.Height := AHeight;
    LBitmap.Width := AWidth;

    //  width * height * 3 bytes/pixel
    SetLength(LPixels, AWidth * AHeight * 3);

    //  tell open gl which buffer we're interested in
    glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);
    //  read pixels
    glReadPixels(0, 0, AWidth, AHeight, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, @LPixels);
    //  scan each line from bitmap
    for Index := 0 to AHeight -1 do begin
      LLine := LBitmap.ScanLine[ Index ];
      //  move data from LPixels to LLine, data size = Width * 3(bytes/pixel)
      Move(LPixels[ Index * AWidth ], LLine^[0], AWidth * 3);
    end; // for Index := 0 to AHeight -1 do begin
    //  save the bitmap
    LBitmap.SaveToFile(AFileName);
    //  if we reached this line, we're pretty much OK
    Result := True;
  finally
    LBitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```